# Export in wolframscript moves focus to Mathematica app

Tags: export, mac-os-x, scripting

I'm running Mathematica 11 from command line on OS X El Capitan.
As far as I know, I can only pass command line arguments using the `wolframscript` command.
Here's my minimal working example:

**try.wl:**

```
Export[
"try.pdf",
Plot[Power[x,ToExpression[$ScriptCommandLine[[2]]]],{x,0,1}]
]
```

I invoke it with e.g.

```
wolframscript -script try.wl 2
```

The script is executed correctly, but my OS switches the focus to a temporary Mathematica window - which basically does not even appear, but I can read `Mathematica` on my upper left corner and see the dot under the icon in the app dock.

This is all rather annoying for running in batch mode, as it interrupts everything else I'm doing.
Any ideas?

Hint: the Export command seems to play some role. Adding `;`s doesn't help.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It is true that `Export` will launch a front end process which has no windows but does show up in the dock. However, I cannot reproduce any focus switch. Perhaps I do not understand what you mean by focus switch. I can keep using another program while the script runs. Its window won't stop being the selected one.

Comment: The behavior I experience is different: the selected window changes to Mathematica. That might be an OS problem more than a Mathematica one then, crap. It would however be nice to run `Export` without the need for the front end process, given that even `Plot` does not need it...

Comment: How can it focus the Mathematica window when the front end that is started has no visible windows whatsoever?  Can you give step by step instructions to reproduce the problem?  Restart your computer to start with a clean slate. Then describe what I should do, step by step, to trigger the problem. Describe what happens on your machine, and what you want to happen instead.

Comment: The front end is necessary for all rendering and PDF generation. `Plot` involves no rendering (it just generates a `Graphics` expression), so it doesn't need a front end. `Export`, `Rasterize`, etc. do.

Comment: @Szabolcs Clearly a subtle and stupid OS problem. After following your suggestions, I realised the issue is noticeable only when the terminal is run in full screen mode (I do have strange habits indeed).
Can you reproduce this?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot. I tried a few variations (such as already having an existing Mathematica session running) but I cannot. I have M11.0.1 on OS X 10.12.3 Sierra.

Comment: To be clear, a front end does (and should) get launched. The white dot does appear under the Mathematica icon in the dock. But focus doesn't change to Mathematica. It stays on the Terminal window, regardless of whether it is in fullscreen mode or not.

Comment: I'm running OS X 10.11.6, for what it's worth - clean after launch according to your suggestion.
Might be fullscreen mode has received some updates.

Comment: Do you have any special window focusing settings turned on in OS X?  Anything at all that differs from the default?  I am out of ideas.  If you have M11.0.0, try upgrading to 11.0.1.  It will fix a few bugs so it's worth doing this  anyway.